# Position one <div> under another

Tags: html, css

Basically as the title says, I'm trying to position one `<div>` of an image underneath the other but having trouble.

My CSS so far is:

```
#rightimg img{
  max-width: 25%;
  height: inherit;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  float:right;
  padding:0px;
}

#rightimg:after{
  content:'';
  clear:both;
  clear:right;
}
```

`clear: right;` is my most recent attempt to alter the issue but didn't work - tried removing `clear: both;` and having just the right one, but didn't work. Also tried using `<br>` but just moved the entire `<div>` Image to follow:

[image]

Trying to achieve (blue is image, white is text):
[image]

Current HTML:

```
<div id="rightimg">
    <img src="SLL/hammer.png"/>
</div>

    <div id="right_col">
        <h2>Letting Management</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri et case persecuti, enim iuvaret nec at, adhuc labores eos ei. Eu eum prima ignota, falli audiam minimum ne ius. His an inani scripta. Case phaedrum ei eos, amet dicam eloquentiam ex pro. An modus perpetua duo, ei mel erat dicat, eam ea mucius argumentum. Sit ea elit accusam, exerci maiorum iudicabit ne mea.</p>
    </div>
```

Not sure if it should go under my column that is floated to the left or right.

Comment: Try: `position: absolute;`

Comment: can you provide a mock up as to what it is you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @AdamJeffers - will add image to show what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Ok cool... now just need your HTML mate ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the blue boxes with your images, and you should be all set. The important thing is you need extra HTML surrounding each element to create rows.

This removes the need for absolute positioning, and allows you to float the items without breaking into other elements above and below them.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden
}
.left_row .content {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  width: 75%
}
.right_row .content {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  width: 75%
}
.right_image,
.left_image {
  background: blue;
  border: solid black 2px;
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%
}
.left_image {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="row right_row">
  <div class="left_image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row left_row">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here. Lorem ipsum content here.
  </div>
  <div class="right_image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok... so, first of all, can I suggest you adopt a responsive framework such as Bootstrap? It will make your life soooo much easier!

Just include this in the `<head>` of you page...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or download the files and include them yourself as local resources.

Then you can use the following markup to give you the architecture you're looking for.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="whatever" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed ultrices ante. Sed dolor est, fringilla id egestas id, pulvinar ac nisl. Integer sed laoreet nisl, id finibus ligula. Proin auctor tempor nunc, quis lobortis justo accumsan et. Duis viverra malesuada tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed ultrices ante. Sed dolor est, fringilla id egestas id, pulvinar ac nisl. Integer sed laoreet nisl, id finibus ligula. Proin auctor tempor nunc, quis lobortis justo accumsan et. Duis viverra malesuada tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="whatever" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="whatever" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed ultrices ante. Sed dolor est, fringilla id egestas id, pulvinar ac nisl. Integer sed laoreet nisl, id finibus ligula. Proin auctor tempor nunc, quis lobortis justo accumsan et. Duis viverra malesuada tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/x30mpo9z/

You can see here that I added 2 classes for left and right floated/positioned images, `.image-left` and `.image-right`. I float the `.content` div left, and the `.row` div is set with a `clear:both`

This fiddle is a very minimal solution that you can expand on.

Answer (score 0):

use nth-child for this,

```
div.main{
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
position:relative;
clear:both;
}
div.img{
width:25%;
float:left;
height:200px;
}

div.main:nth-child(2) div.img{
 float:right;
}

div.content{
width:75%;
float:right;
height:200px;    
}
div.img img{
width:100%;
}

div.main:nth-child(2) div.content{
 float:left;
}


<div class="main">
  <div class="img"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="img"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="img"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can build a "CSS table" using the `display` property with values `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell`. It renders just like a table, except it isn't so it is not semantically associated with tabular data.

```css
.view-table {
  display: table;
}

.view-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.view-row > div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.view-row > div > * {
  vertical-align: top;
}

img {
  max-height: 100px;
}

.view-row > .with-img {
  width: 1%; /* So that the cell adjusts to the width of its contents. */
}
```

```html
<div class="view-table">
  <div class="view-row">
    <div class="with-img">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Kittyply_edit1.jpg/800px-Kittyply_edit1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>Industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view-table">
  <div class="view-row">
    <div>Industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets 
    </div>
    <div class="with-img">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Kittyply_edit1.jpg/800px-Kittyply_edit1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view-table">
  <div class="view-row">
    <div class="with-img">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Kittyply_edit1.jpg/800px-Kittyply_edit1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>Industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```